# C++ rethrow does not call custom terminate handler

Tags: c++, exception, throw

I have used custom terminate handler which works fine if I call throw with a type or explicitly call terminate(), but if I use rethow i.e throw; , the custom terminate handler is not called, only default terminate handler is called causing the program to abort. Code confirms to C++03. Could anyone help me to find out the problem ? Thank you in advance

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <exception>      
using namespace std;

void myunexpected() {
    cerr << "CUSTOM unexpected handler called ------ \n";
    throw 0;     // throws int (in exception-specification)
}
void myterminate () {
  cerr << "CUSTOM terminate handler called ------ \n";
  //abort();  // forces abnormal termination
  exit(0);
}
void myfunction() throw (int) {
    throw 'x';   // throws char (not in exception-specification)
}

int main(void) {
    set_unexpected(myunexpected);
    set_terminate(myterminate);
    int a = 1;
    try{
        try {
            myfunction();
        }
        catch (int) {
            cerr << "caught int\n";
            throw string("sree");
        }
        catch (...) { cerr << "caught some other exception type\n"; }
    }
    catch (string& s)
    {
        cerr << a << "caught STRING " << s << endl;
        //throw 0;     //ok --> implicitly calls terminate()-->myterminate
        //terminate(); //ok --> explicitly calls terminate()-->myterminate
        throw;  //--------- Calls default throw Why ??? 

    }
    return 0; 
}
```

OUTPUT

```
CUSTOM unexpected handler called ------
caught int
1caught STRING sree

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

--------------------------------
Process exited after 8.238 seconds with return value 255
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/P8Limi works for me

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using DEV CPP IDE . It uses gcc 4.8.1

Comment: I tried in another which uses g++ 4.8.3 in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp0x_online.php, its working fine there (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp0x_online.php). I am not sure of the issue with gcc version or dev cpp